# I can't update my Mac to El Capitan

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, software-update

For some reason, I can't update my MacBook Air to the new update "OS X El Capitan".
The update is on "pause" and I can't start it again, I simply cannot click on it.  I attached an image of what I see below.
Does anyone know how I can solve this? I've tried rebooting several times, but that seems to have no affect.

[image: download paused]

Comment: The update is on "pause" or the download from iTunes?

Comment: the update says it's on *pause* but i can't click it, i can't click the button in app store either

Comment: I meant App Store.  Oops.  What you need to do is delete the *Install OS X El Capitan" folder from `/Applications`.  In Terminal type `sudo rm -rf /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app` and you should be able to restart your download.

Comment: This is going great - There's no sign of that folder in applications or in my computer at all. There's just that "button" i can't press..

Comment: To be clear, where is it you see this icon? Is it on boot as the only thing on the screen, or is it within another application?

Answer (score 1):

It seems somehow version of OS X on your mac is corrupted. Try restoring it using utilities in OS X recovery system (built-in).

To start up from OS X Recovery, hold down Command (⌘)-R immediately after turning on or restarting your Mac. Release when you see the Apple logo. If you can't start up from OS X Recovery, try holding down Option-Command-R to start up from OS X Internet Recovery. Startup is complete when you see the OS X Utilities window. Use one of the listed utilities to restore your mac.

- If you have time machine backup, select Restore From Time Machine Backup.
- Otherwise, select Reinstall OS X. OS X Recovery (Command-R) installs the version of OS X that was last installed on your Mac. OS X Internet Recovery (Option-Command-R) installs the version that originally came with your Mac.
- If still not able to restore, browse the web and find help for your mac using safari (Get Online Help Option).

Comment: will this delete everything in my computer?

Comment: No, If you have time machine backup (option 1). Otherwise using option 2, it will delete everything. There is one more option in OS X utility - disk utility. Maybe you can use that to see what's wrong with your disk.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Time Machine Backup of your mac, you can boot it into Recovery Mode, and do a fresh install of the OS. Might solve the problem. Alternatively, it could be the amount of disk space left on your SSD.